# Unit Testing for dynamodb-onetable

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Unit Testing and wanted to stub dynamodb-onetable library. I was trying to stub getData() from getDetails.ts file but it shows that "**OneTableArgError: Missing Name Property**". Because this getProjectDetails() contain new Table() class.
How to stub dynamodb-onetable so that I can get data in dataDetails variable. I was doing something like this in getEmp.spec.ts

dataDetailsStub = sinon.stub(DataService , "getData");

```
------lambda.ts
     import { DynamoDBClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
     import Dynamo from 'dynamodb-onetable/Dynamo';
     export const client = new Dynamo({
                            client: new DynamoDBClient({
                            region: REGION,   }),
                           });

-------DataService.ts
import { client } from '../lambda';
const workspaceTable = new Table({
  client,
  name: TableName,
  schema,
  logger: true,
  partial: false,
});
const projectDetail = workspaceTable.getModel('empDetail');

export default class **DataService** {
  static getData = async (empId: string, type: string) => {
    const params = {
      projectId,
      type
    };
    const response = await empDetail.find(params);
    logger.trace('response', { response });
    return response;   };
 }


------getDetails.ts
    const dataDetails= await DataService.getData(
      empId,
      'EMPLOYEE-SAVEDATA'
    );
```

I was trying to stub the DataService.getData() but getting error saying "OneTableArgError: Missing "name" property". I want to get data in dataDetailsStub whatever i am sending while mocking the getData()

```
const dataDetailsStub = sinon.stub(DataService , "getData").return({emp object});
```

Can anyone help me out on this. I'm really got stuck in this. Thanks in advance